# how to get object from array by value inside desired object by mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

i have following bson data in mongoDB

```
{
 [
  {
     partyName : "p1",
     poNumber : "789",
  },
  {
     partyName : "p2",
     poNumber : "700",
  },
  {
     partyName : "p3",
     poNumber : "889",
  }
 ]
}
```

i want object from partyName for example if partyName is p1 then i want this

```
{
     partyName : "p1",
     poNumber : "789",
  }
```

i searched on the internet but not find relative result, all i found that  query.elemMatch may help but i don't know how to use it please help me with the solution ( i want to use only mongoose )

Comment: Can you post your `mongoose` schema declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Fill in the `EntityName` and `mainEntityName` parts as your schema's names:

```js
await EntityName.findOne({ mainEntityName: { $elemMatch: { partyName: "p1" } } });
```

Instead of ***p1***, add your parameter that came from the `req.query`.

To reach all elements that match with your filter; use the `find()` method:

```js
await EntityName.find({ mainEntityName: { $elemMatch: { partyName: "p1" } } });
```

Comment: above solution only gives first matched option, i have so many objects so i want all object which has value p1. what can i changed in above solution so that i can get all matched options

Comment: just do this, await EntityName.find( { mainEntityName: { $elemMatch: { partyName: "p1" } } }). find() gives you all elements which matched with filters. findOne() gives you only first element. If you wanna take last one, need to add sort({_id: -1}) etc.

Comment: i tried it, still it gives me first object

Comment: Can you share your code