# Update the value of an array by index in document in MongoDB with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern

I am creating a e-commerce website in react and I am adding a multiple address functionality, but I am new to MongoDB and I have no Idea how do I update a value of an array by it's index, I am taking the details of the address by destructuring the `req.body` and taking the `addressId` which is the index of the `address` array which the user wants to update, I want to update the array `address` at the position of `addressId`(0, 1, 2, 3...).

or if I can update the array in anyway by it's index then it would also work for me
please help me out.

my current code.

```
exports.updateAddress = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { userId, addressId, firstname, lastname, company, phone, address1, address2, city, zipcode, state, defaultAdd } = req.body;
    const result = await User.updateOne({ _id: userId }, {
      address: { // this address needs to be updated by the index.
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        company: company,
        phone: phone,
        address1: address1,
        address2: address2,
        city: city,
        zipcode: zipcode,
        state: state,
        defaultAdd: defaultAdd
      }
    })
    console.log(result)
    res.status(200).json({
      data: true
    })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

my user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    requried: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'basic',
    enum: ["basic", "supervisor", "admin"]
  },
  accesstoken: {
    type: String
  },
  address: [ // this is the address array schema 
    {
      addressId: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
      },
      phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      address1: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      address2: {
        type: String
      },
      city: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      zipcode: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      state: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      defaultAdd: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Comment: You may check this answer that could be helpful for you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658247/how-to-get-object-from-array-by-value-inside-desired-object-by-mongoose/73662686#73662686 . You can use $elemMatch in first object parameter for addressId in the address array in updateOne method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give it a filter of the `addressId` then it will go there where the `addressId:addressId` (1, 2, 3...), then just set the values of the keys as you want something like this

```
const result = await User.updateOne({ _id: userId, 'address.addressId': addressId }, {
      $set: {
        'address.$.firstname': firstname,
        'address.$.lastname': lastname,
        'address.$.company': company,
        'address.$.phone': phone,
        'address.$.address1': address1,
        'address.$.address2': address2,
        'address.$.city': city,
        'address.$.zipcode': zipcode,
        'address.$.state': state,
        'address.$.defaultAdd': defaultAdd
      }
    })
```